# When I am listing my PHP results in a table, how do I change the border-bottom-color when the data changes?

Tags: php

On my web site, I am returning a list of home inspection projects with inspection dates.  I have several inspections per day and I sort by "datetimeinspection".  When my table displays, I'd like a heavier line weight or different line color under the last of each day's inspections.

I'm pretty clear on changing properties based on the data for each row.  For example, in the sample code below I left the portion where I used the data of the "status" column to set each row's colors.  The challenge I have here is comparing data between rows to know where to change the border-bottom.

```
<table>
    <tr style="height:30px; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">
        <td>Job Number</td>
        <td>Insured Name</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>County</strong></td>
        <td>Inpection Scope</strong></td>
        <td>Date of Loss</strong></td>
        <td>Inspection Date</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <? while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        if ($row['status'] == "Scheduled") { ?>
            <tr style="color: #16B148; ">
        <? } elseif ($row['status'] == "Closed") { ?>
            <tr style="color: #CDD4D7; text-decoration:line-through">
        <? } elseif ($row['status'] == "Inspected") { ?>
            <tr style="background-color: #92D050 ">
        <? } elseif ($row['status'] == "Delay by NI") { ?>
            <tr style="color: #9D16B1 ">
        <? } elseif ($row['status'] == "Delay by rep") { ?>
            <tr style="color: #9D16B1 ">
        <? } elseif ($row['status'] == "Tentative") { ?>
            <tr style="color: green ">
        <? } elseif ($row['status'] == "New") { ?>
            <tr style="color: red; font-weight: 250 ">
        <? } elseif ($row['status'] == "Left Voicemail") { ?>
            <tr style="color: #92D050 ">
        <? } ?>
        <td><? echo $row["claimnumber"] ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row["insuredname"] ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row["insuredaddress"] ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row["insuredcity"] ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row["insuredcounty"] ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row["inspectionscope"] ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row["dateofloss"] ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row["datetimeinspection"] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <? } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Here in this `datetimeinspection` column do you update `date-time` , whenever  changes occur ? if yes you can use this to compare today `date` or `time`  and where today date or current time  is present that means changes has done , so just apply your css on that `row`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the idea on sample data

```
<?php

//15 rows
$dates = [
'2019-08-19 00:00:00',
'2019-08-20 00:00:00',
'2019-08-21 00:00:00',
'2019-08-21 00:00:00',
'2019-08-21 00:00:00',
'2019-08-22 00:00:00',
'2019-08-22 00:00:00',
'2019-08-22 00:00:00',
'2019-08-23 00:00:00',
'2019-08-23 00:00:00',
'2019-08-23 00:00:00',
'2019-08-24 00:00:00',
'2019-08-24 00:00:00',
'2019-08-25 00:00:00',
'2019-08-25 00:00:00',
];

$lastDay = "";
$i = -1;
foreach ($dates as $date){
    $i++;
    $dateTime = new DateTime($date);
    if ($lastDay != $dateTime->format("d") && $i != 0){
        echo ($i - 1) . " is a last row in a day\n";
    }
    $lastDay = $dateTime->format("d");
}

echo $i . " is a last row in a day\n";; // last row must be a last row in a day also
```

This outputs

```
0 is a last row in a day
1 is a last row in a day 
4 is a last row in a day 
7 is a last row in a day 
10 is a last row in a day 
12 is a last row in a day 
14 is a last row in a day
```

live demo (https://3v4l.org/jc0BY)

To apply it on your code example, you can do something like this

```
<?php

$rows = [];
$lastDay = "";
$i = -1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $i++;
    $dateTime = new DateTime($row['datetimeinspection']);
    $rows[] = $row;
    if ($lastDay != $dateTime->format("d") && $i != 0){
        $rows[$i - 1]['lastRowInDay'] = true;
    }
    $lastDay = $dateTime->format("d");
}
$rows[$i]['lastRowInDay'] = true;

foreach ($rows as $row){
    if (!empty ($row['lastRowInDay'])){
        //this is the last row in the day , give it the CSS that you want
         echo '<tr style="border-bottom:2px solid red">';
    } else if ($row['status'] == "Scheduled"){
        echo '<tr style="color: #16B148; ">';
    } else if ($row['status'] == "Closed"){
        echo '<tr style="color: #CDD4D7; text-decoration:line-through">';
    } else if ($row['status'] == "Inspected"){
        echo '<tr style="color: #92D050; ">';
    } else if ($row['status'] == "Delay by NI"){
        echo '<tr style="color: #9D16B1; ">';
    } else if ($row['status'] == "Tentative"){
        echo '<tr style="color: #green; ">';
    } else if ($row['status'] == "New"){
        echo '<tr style="color: red; font-weight: 250">';
    } else if ($row['status'] == "Left Voicemail"){
        echo '<tr style="color: #92D050;">';
    }
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row["insuredname"]) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row["insuredcity"]) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row["insuredcounty"]) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row["inspectionscope"]) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row["dateofloss"]) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row["datetimeinspection"]) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row["insuredname"]) . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>'

}
```

Comment: Hi Accountant, and thanks for your answer.  I'm finally getting the chance to try and implement this, but I'm still a bit confused.  Can you give me an example of what the formatting would look like to make the bottom border of the row to be colored red, for exanmple?  The section where you say "//this is the last row in the day , give it the CSS that you want", I'm not sure how the syntax goes.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'll work that into my code tomorrow!